# Clearing memory after loading shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

Although I do the suggested steps, I get a memory leak. I load and delete shaders as follows:

```
glCreateShader
glShaderSource
glCompileShader
glAttachShader
glLinkProgram
glUseProgram
glDetachShader
glDeleteShader
glUseProgram(0);
glDeleteProgram
```

`glLingProgram()` seems to cause the leak when I do all these steps in a loop. Below is my test code. Could you please help me find out the problem? (The code is based on the tutorials on http://opengl-tutorial.org/).

**EDIT:** I think this occurs only when the vertex shader includes an `attribute` type.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream("VertexShader.vs", std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open()) {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }
    else {
        printf("Cannot open vertex shader!");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream("FragmentShader.fs", std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()) {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line)) {
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        }
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }
    else {
        printf("Cannot open fragment shader!");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);

    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    glUseProgram(ProgramID);

    glDetachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    glUseProgram(0);

    glDeleteProgram(ProgramID);
}
```

Comment: How did you identify the memory leak?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Running this code (with the only additions that create a GLFW window and initiate GLEW) cause a fast leak, and I observe this from the system monitor tool. It reaches to a gigabyte in only a few seconds.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I figured out that this problem occurs if the vertex shader includes an `attribute` type.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the driver :( Can you try on a machine with a different graphics adapter (preferably from a different manufacturer)?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I will try to find another machine. By the way, I have just saw that two attributes cause this, not only one.

Comment: You need to do some testing to find out where the leak is happening.  Try recording and outputting the size of your containers after you fill them under circumstances that cause the leak and those that don't.

Comment: @kkuryllo the code shown uses no long-lived containers. And note "Running this code (with the only additions that create a GLFW window and initiate GLEW)"

Comment: Btw, can you share what graphics adapter you are using?

Comment: By the way, it is a little ridiculous that you are reading your shader files line-by-line. C++ stream I/O encourages some really bad behavior it seems.

Comment: @kkuryllo glLinkProgram() seems to cause the leak. When I delete that line, the no leak occurs.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0102] (rev 09), OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.0.4, OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman This code is adapted from a tutorial, and I did not touch that part. Thanks for the warning. I will try to find a better way.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/32d33f0f4ec0ce0eab95

Answer (score 0):

You should load the shaders only at the beginning. Only glUseProgram is intended to be used in the render loop.

Standard template of using a shader is like this:

```
glCreateProgram
glCreateShader
glShaderSource
glCompileShader
glAttachShader
glLinkProgram <- after this line opengl got everything it needs, 
                 you can free shader resources
glDetachShader
glDeleteShader

for{//render loop
   glUseProgram
   //...drawing operations
   glUseProgram(0);
}

glDeleteProgram
```